# Data migration from monolith to microservice (Apache Airflow)

Tags: etl, airflow

We have a multi-tenant monolith system and are moving to a micro-services architecture. We have planned to extract 4 microservices, for data migration we are adding rest endpoint in monolith to fetch the data and endpoint in microservice to insert the data.

On a high-level, the following steps are needed:

1. Rest endpoint in monolith to fetch data, API will be paginated with a filter like tenantId.
2. Process the data or transform the data.
3. Insert the data in a microservice database for microservice will expose the rest endpoint.

I am new to dataflow and would like to know if it is a viable solution.

Following are my constraints:

1. I want to pace data copy like 10 items at a time, so it does not impact by creating load on monolith because it is serving live traffic as well.
2. Ability to retry on failures.

After an initial reading of dataflow, I came up with two options:

Option 1:

I will create a DAG to do ETL with two tasks
Extract and Transform Task: which will call monolith API to fetch data transform and put into S3 bucket.
Load Task: which will insert transformed data

Option 2:

Only one task
Extract, Transform, and Load: No need for S3 bucket. Fetch 10 items, transform, and load into microservice.

I am new to ETL and dataflow so let me know which approach is better. Also in case of retry, is there a way to create checkpoint in airflow say task failed after inserting 100 records in micro-service? When retry happens I don't want to start from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to migrate from monolith to micro-services.

Is it to

1. slowly migrate from Monolithic to Micro-services by distributing traffic between two systems.

or

2. Completely cutover to new Micro-services on a fine day.

If it's the second approach, I would do ETL for data migration.

If it's the first approach -

Implement an CDC/or just changes in monolithic service to publish the persistent operations to Messaging system (Kafka.Rabbit).

Implement the subscriber on Micro-services and update the DB.

Once confident on Pub/Sub implementation, redirect all reads to micro-services system.

Then slowly divert some percentage of persistent calls to micro-services which will do a rest call to old system to update old DB.

Once you are confident on new services and data quality and other requirements(performance), completely cutover to new Micro-services).

** you need to do historic sync before starting the Async Messaging process.

This is one way to smoothly cutover from Monolithic to Micro-services.

Comment: I want to migrate one tenant at a time. When you say  "you need to do historic sync before starting the Async Messaging process." You mean migrating existing data I am looking for the solution for historic data.

Comment: I d suggest ETL process to migrate the historic load. I am not sure about why you want to extract info from read api of monolithic, I d prefer extracting data directly from Database.